# button to Check if query exists using form input something i missed

Tags: php, forms

Sorry to post, maybe is an ordinary question, i front with a problem and I don t know what i miss.. I tried to made a button to check a input value if that value exists in the database, but doesnt show me nothing...

So I have more `td` with input, but i want to check only one the `link` (if the link exist show a message to user)

```
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="page_new_parse_stiinta.php" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
      <tr>
        <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#F5E4A9">Page Full Title</td>
        <td width="88%" bgcolor="#F5E4A9"><input name="titlu" type="text" id="titlu" size="90" maxlength="110" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">Link-ul paginii</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="link" type="text" id="link" maxlength="544"  value="" />**<input formmethod="post" name="checkLink" type="submit" value="verifica linkul daca exista" formaction="">** 
          (What the link to this page will display as)</td> 
      </tr>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Create this page now"  onClick="javascript:submit_form();"/>
         </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

When i submit the button `checkLink` I want to check in the database if the input for `link` exist
and I made this

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["checkLink"])){
$checkLink = $_POST['link'];
echo $checkLink;
echo "test";
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT link FROM stiinta LIKE link = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $checkLink);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($check);//variabla pe care o vrei
while ($stmt->fetch())    {
   $check;    // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
}
$resultCheck=$stmt->num_rows();
$checkMesajLink = "";
if($resultCheck > 0){
    $checkMesajLink .= "linkul exista alege altu";

    }
    else{
        $checkMesajLink .= "linkul este ok, poate fi adaugat";
        header('Location: ../create_page_stiinta.php');

        }

}
```

and the showing message

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["checkLink"])){
echo $checkMesajLink;}?>
```

but when doesnt show me nothing...

Comment: did you start the session everywhere? and where's no JS to support the `validate_form ( )` function.

Comment: is i have this on the starting page `<?php require '../conx.php';  
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
 } else{
  header('Location: ../login.php');
  }
?>` i deteled the validata_form() but didnot work

Comment: if it is a form, why do you just check session? Do kinda if is set the $_POST and if its not empty, also do client-side validation

Comment: sorry I m newbie in codeing can you show me a exemple?